# get_home_url in wordpress returns wrong url

Tags: wordpress, url, restore

After having restored wordpress under a subdomain for development purposes, I have a very strange behaviour in the frontend.  After the first 8 calls of get_home_url where the correct url is returned, only the old url is returned. The behaviour is independent of the theme used. Both in the DB and in wp-config.php the subdomain is entered correctly. I have done a SQL dump as well as searched the filesystem for the old domain name. Nothing to find. I also checked the .htaccess, nothing to find. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance
Folker

searched the sql dump and the filesystem for parts of wrong url, nothing to find.
disabled nearly all plugins, nothimg changed.